# database connection error fatal errors

Tags: php, mysqli

having an issue with connecting to my DB (been a long long day) - so anyway I am creating a simple search query into my DB but getting scripting errors - so here is my code:

```
<?php

mysqli_connect("localhost", "my username", "my password");
mysqli_select_db("smudged");

$search = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

$find_image = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'smd_images' WHERE 'img_description' LIKE'%$search%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_image))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo "$name";
}

?>
```

Here is my error:

search.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /marble/search.php on line 4 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_sring() in /marble/search.php on line 6

Comment: Well, it was a long day it is time to sleep. All these errors caused by mere typos. Just sleep it off and fix in the morning in a wink.

Comment: I have made the edits to the typos....any ideas?

Comment: New error:
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /marble/search.php on line 4 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /marble/search.php on line 6 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /marble/search.php on line 8 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /marble/search.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

Typo. Instead of `mysql_real_escape_sring()` you probably meant `mysql_real_escape_string()`